# Questions related to the Dedekind psi function $\psi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, mobius-function, kronecker-delta, modular-function

The Wikipedia article [Dedekind psi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function) indicates the Dedekind psi function defined in formula (1) below was introduced by Richard Dedekind in connection with modular functions.

---

**(1)** $\quad\psi(n)=n \prod\limits_{p|n}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)$

---

I've searched the Internet a bit and the only connection I've found between $\psi(n)$ and modular functions is documented in the MathOverflow question [A conjecture related to the Cohen-Oesterlé dimension formula of spaces of modular forms for half-integer weights](https://mathoverflow.net/q/161948) but the MathOverflow question implies this is a recent conjecture.

---

> **Question (1)**: What connection did Richard Dedekind establish between modular functions and the Dedekind psi function ψ(n)? Was it the same as the conjecture in the MathOverflow question linked above?

---

I've found the [Dedekind psi summatory function](https://oeis.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_summatory_function) defined in formula (2) below to be interesting as I've derived a number of conjectured relationships with other number theoretic functions such as those illustrated in formulas (3) to (9) below. The Dedekind psi function is related to the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ as illustrated in formula (2) below and the Riemann hypothesis. I've read the Riemann hypothesis is satisfied if-and-only-if $f(n)=\psi(n)/n-e^\gamma\log\log n < 0$ for all integers $n > n_0 = 30$ (see [Riemann hypothesis from the Dedekind psi function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3239)). The derivation of this result is based on the relationship $\psi(n)=\sigma_1(n)$ when $n$ is a square-free number which also perhaps provides insight into the conjectured relationships illustrated in formulas (8) and (9) below.

---

**(2)** $\quad\Psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\psi(n)\qquad\qquad\qquad\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi(n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s-1)\,\zeta (s)}{\zeta (2\,s)},\quad\Re(s)>2$

---

**(3)** $\quad U(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\delta_{1,n}\overset{?}{=}\sum\limits_{n\le x}\frac{rad(n)\,\lambda(n)\,\psi(n)}{n}\Psi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

---

**(4)** $\quad Q(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\left|\mu(n)\right|\overset{?}{=}\sum\limits_{n\le x}\mu(n)\,n\,\Psi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

**(5)** $\quad\Psi(x)\overset{?}{=}\sum\limits_{n\le x} n\,Q\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

---

**(6)** $\quad\Phi(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\phi(n)\overset{?}{=}\sum\limits_{n\le x}\lambda(n)\,2^{\,\nu(n)}\,\Psi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

**(7)** $\quad\Psi(x)\overset{?}{=}\sum\limits_{n\le x} 2^{\nu(n)}\,\Phi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

---

**(8)** $\quad \Sigma_1(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\sigma_1(n)\overset{?}{=}\sum\limits_{n\le x}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \sqrt{n}\in \mathbb{Z} \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)\Psi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

**(9)** $\quad\Psi(x)\overset{?}{=}\sum\limits_{n\le x}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \mu \left(\sqrt{n}\right) & \sqrt{n}\in \mathbb{Z} \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right) \Sigma_1\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

---

In the formulas above:

- $\delta_{1,n}$ is the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)
- $rad(n)$ is the [radical of $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) also referred to as the square-free kernel of $n$
- $\lambda(n)$ is the [Liouville function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function)
- $\mu(n)$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)
- $\nu(n)$ is the number of distinct primes in the factorization of $n$
- $\sigma_1(n)$ is the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)

---

> **Question (2)**: Are any of the conjectured relationships illustrated in formulas (3) to (9) above known proven relationships?